# Can't download anything due to proxy

Tags: networking, proxy

I'm using 13.04 for the first time and I am using proxy base server that's why I can't download anything while I use apt-get update then it shows this message

```
coolmonter@coolmonter-HP-ProBook-4431s:~$ apt-get update
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

any suggestion

Comment: This problem should be solved if you use `sudo apt-get update` instead of only `apt-get update`. Then it will be needed to set  proxy settings for `apt.conf` if you are using intternet behind a proxy server. For that you follow the answer of Rana Muhammad Waqas below. Besides you should set system proxy also.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried `sudo apt-get update`? It seems to be complaining about the permissions required.

Answer (score 3):

Check the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf`.

After applying the proxy "system wide", the contents of `/etc/apt/apt.conf` are like:

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://172.16.0.2:8080/";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://172.16.0.2:8080/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://172.16.0.2:8080/";
```

Here `ipadress-of-proxy-server:port` I am using  `172.16.0.2:8080` as sample. Use your proxy server address and port whatever you have. But, in order to make this work, you must add your username and password into it (unless you use an unnamed proxy) as follows:

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://<username>:<password>@172.16.0.2:8080";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://<username>:<password>@172.16.0.2:8080/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://<username>:<password>@172.16.0.2:8080/";
```

To edit the file run in the following command in terminal (instead of `gedit` you can use your any text editor you wish).

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf
```

Next save the file and run the following command in terminal to make system understand the changes in APT's settings,

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Here you are good to go to install things from both a terminal and the Software Center.

(Note that by the `apt.conf` settings the proxy will only work on software-center/terminal with apt-get.)

There is more information here at [AptGet/Howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto) in the Ubuntu [official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/).